# This function should take an id, a name and an email as arguments, and return an object with `id`, `name` and `email` properties

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
function makePersonObject(id, name, email) 
{
  const personObject = {  
    id: 3,
    name: "Baby Yoda",
    email: "baby@yoda.com",
  }
  return personObject
};
```

I keep getting undefined when I run the code, does anyone know why?

Comment: "Keep getting undefined" from *what* exactly?  All this code does is define a function.  Where do you ever call that function?  It's also worth noting that your function ignores the values you send it.

Comment: Please show the entire code (including the call to `makePersonObject`!) and the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: You never use any of the function parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should not be returning undefined, unless you are not using the function correctly. Furthermore, you aren't using the arguments to fill the object. Check this:

```js
function makePersonObject(id, name, email) {
  return { id, name, email };
};

console.log(makePersonObject(1, 'Jane Doe', 'jdoe@acme.com'));
```